# Invalid array length

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test this component on vue, but when I run the test I get the message down bellow:

```
RangeError: Invalid array length

       96 |         this.changeLogs.marketConfiguration.productTypes
       97 |       );
    >  98 |       return [
          |              ^
       99 |         ...new Set(
      100 |           productTypes.flatMap((productType) => productType.domains || [])
      101 |         )
```

I'm using Jest, with vue-test-utils.

And this is the function:

```
affectedDomains(): string {
      const productTypes: ProductTypeConfiguration[] = Object.values(
        this.changeLogs.marketConfiguration.productTypes
      );
      return [
        ...new Set(
          productTypes.flatMap((productType) => productType.domains || [])
        )
      ].join(', ');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, in my case was to set the `"downlevelIteration": true,` on `tsconfig.json`.

> Downleveling is TypeScript’s term for transpiling to an older version
> of JavaScript. This flag is to enable support for a more accurate
> implementation of how modern JavaScript iterates through new concepts
> in older JavaScript runtimes.

[More info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#downlevelIteration)